# Filtering children by parent value in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with three document types:

- Lead - have and id and type (child of Account)
- Account - have an id
- Payment - have and id, type and account_id (child of Account)

They all are in parent-child relationship.
I want to get statistics about which lead types do i have (group by type) and then count how many payments of this certain type do i have.

I came to this query, but i'm unable to filter child aggregation by parent's type.
Query to `Lead` type

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "payments_count": {
          "filter": {
            "and": [
              {
                "has_parent": {
                  "type": "account",
                  "query": {
                    "filtered": {
                      "query": {
                        "match_all": {}
                      },
                      "filter": {
                        "and": [
                          {
                            "has_child": {
                              "type": "payment",
                              "query": {
                                "filtered": {
                                  "query": {
                                    "match_all": {}
                                  },
                                  "filter": {
                                    "and": [
                                      {
                                        "term": {
                                          "type": ?????????
                                        }
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the last has_child filter i want to know how to filter children by `lead.type` of it's parent, something like this:

```
"filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "term": {
          "type": "$lead.type"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Also, i can't inverse this query due to another aggregations going on `lead` type.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: can you provide some sample data and expected results, that would make things much easier for someone to provide help.

Answer (score 1):

You are running your query against type "lead" , so if you want to filter on "lead.type", you should do it as the first filter aggregation before stepping into its parent.

```
"payments_count": {
  "filter": {
    "and": [
     {
        "term": {
          "type": "$lead.type"
        }
     },
     {
       "has_parent": {
       ...
```

Maybe my query also helps as it is a little similar: [Term Filter on a nested field called id does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36573853/filter-aggregation-returns-0-where-it-should-be-1)