# Term Filter on a nested field called id does not work as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a very strange problem/bug that I dont understand. I have a child (course) - parent (college) relationship. I query for courses that belong to a certain college, which works fine. Due to the concept of my application, I also need to query for colleges that have courses that belong to a certain college and than aggregate over the result. I am using this concept for different aggregations and everything works fine except for this one case which does not make sense to me. Please note: I have two types - college and course - and the type course has also a nested object called college. This is nedded to be able to to certain aggregations as parent-aggregations are not supported in ES. This concept works very well for me and I don't think it has anything to do with the mentioned problem/bug.

Thanks in advance, Hannes

Mapping (reduced):

```html
types:
                college:
                    mappings:
                        id: ~
                        premium: { "type": "boolean" }
                        boost: { "type": "boolean" }
                course:
                    mappings:
                        _all: { "analyzer": "text" }
                        id: { "type": "string", "analyzer": "term" }
                        name: { "type": "string", "analyzer": "text" }
                        types: { "type": "string", "analyzer": "term" }
                        college:
                            type: "object"
                            properties:
                                id: { "type": "string", "analyzer": "term" }
                                name: { "type": "string", "analyzer": "text" }
                    _parent:
                        type: "college"
```

Query:

```html
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "has_child": {
          "type": "course",
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "match_all": {}
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "college.id": [
                            "371"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "children": {
      "children": {
        "type": "course"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "filtered": {
          "filter": {
            "query": {
              "filtered": {
                "query": {
                  "match_all": {}
                },
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "college.id": [
                            "371"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "abschluss": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "degree",
                "size": 0
              },
              "aggs": {
                "unique": {
                  "cardinality": {
                    "field": "_parent",
                    "precision_threshold": 500
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "coursecount": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "_parent",
                "size": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20
}
```

Result:

```html
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "studiengaenge_dev",
            "_type": "college",
            "_id": "371",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "id": "371",
               "premium": true,
               "boost": null
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "children": {
         "doc_count": 15,
         "filtered": {
            "doc_count": 0,
            "coursecount": {
               "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
               "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
               "buckets": []
            },
            "abschluss": {
               "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
               "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
               "buckets": []
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: I am running ES 1.7.2

Comment: If I rename the field "id" to something else "collegeId" the query works as expected. Maybe the name id is reserved in ES can not be used in term filter? I leave the question as unanswered but this definetely works for me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I renamed the question and answer it myself so that other people can find it. It seems that a field called "id" is kind of reserved/preconfigured, so that it can not be used in term filters. Renaming the field to something else solved my problem.

```js
"filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                      {
                        "terms": {
                          "college.myId": [
                            "371"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                }
```